# make high priority of external css class than internal and inline css

Tags: css

I want to make high priority of external CSS class than internal class and inline CSS class. Is It possible? How can I do that?

Comment: you could use `!important` to make the priority high, but it is not recommended...

Comment: You should use the `!important` tag in your external CSS file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its bad practice but can be done.

If you put !important after your selector it should overide inline styles.

Idealy though you would remove the inline markup.

Example

```
.myclass{
   color : red !important;
}
```

Comment: I am not really in favour of `!important` and encourage anyone to use it

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible you can use `!important` in your external css classes to give them high priority...rather **inline** & **embed** css